# Compiled google protocol buffers are not working (C++)

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I downloaded google protocol buffers 3.6.0 and the correct protoc.exe for 3.6.0.

I have protoc.exe in the same directory as my .proto files and I hacve run:

```
protoc -I=. --cpp_out=. ./xxxxxxx.proto
```

I get my .h and .cc files but when I try to compile my program that runs them I get errors like:

> google/protobuf/stubs/mutex.h(81): error C2614:
>   'google::protobuf::internal::MutexLockMaybe' : illegal member
>   initialization: 'mu_' is not a base or member

(I am using VS2012)

Any ideas

Answer (score 4):

From [Protocol Buffers 3.6.0](https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases):

> Starting from this release, we now require C++11. For those we cannot
>   yet upgrade to C++11, we will try to keep the 3.5.x branch updated
>   with critical bug fixes only.

As seen from [this table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx) VS 2012 has a lot of C++11 features not implemented.

So your options: use the older google protocol buffers 3.5 or use the newest visual studio. Or gcc if you can.

Answer (score 2):

You should use an older compiler for protobuf. The 2.6.1 is ok and I use it. Or switch to VS 2015 / 2017 and develop there. I would advise VS 2017 for C++ 11.